# no bean named > 'mystoreBrandCategoryCodeValueProvider' available (hybris)

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

> Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.exceptions.IndexerRuntimeException:
>   de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.exceptions.IndexerException:
>   Failed to index item with PK 8796431187969: No bean named
>   'mystoreBrandCategoryCodeValueProvider' available
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
>           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
>           at de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.indexer.strategies.impl.DefaultIndexerStrategy.runWorkers(DefaultIndexerStrategy.java:141)
>   ~[solrfacetsearchserver.jar:?]

I get this error when i try to go to localhost for mystore.

My steps:

- i created b2b from b2c as described on helphybris
- it is working well because i can visit powertools website
- I copied all impexes from powertools to mystore  which is under `mystoreinitialdata/import`
- then i went to `backoffice/wcms` and saw my store as url
- and also i could see my catalogs on `catalogs` tab; product, catalog and classification. Just like powertools.

What i want is, with powertools impexes copied to mystore, i want to see powertools items under mystore.

But it gives error which i posted in the beginning.

I only copied impexes.

For example

```
mystore/solr.impex
```

has

```
;$solrIndexedType; color         ;string;;;Refine;Alpha; 4000;true;;mystoreVariantCategoryCodeValueProvider;categoryFacetDisplayNameProvider;defaultTopValuesProvider
```

which i copied from powertools. But powertools has

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/> 

    <alias alias="b2bAcceleratorCoreSystemSetup" name="powertoolsStoreSystemSetup" />
    <bean id="powertoolsStoreSystemSetup" class="de.hybris.platform.powertoolsstore.setup.PowertoolsStoreSystemSetup" parent="abstractCoreSystemSetup">
        <property name="powertoolsCoreDataImportService" ref="powertoolsCoreDataImportService"/>
        <property name="powertoolsSampleDataImportService" ref="powertoolsSampleDataImportService"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="powertoolsSampleDataImportService" class="de.hybris.platform.powertoolsstore.services.dataimport.impl.PowertoolsSampleDataImportService" 
        parent="sampleDataImportService">
    </bean>
    <bean id="powertoolsCoreDataImportService" class="de.hybris.platform.powertoolsstore.services.dataimport.impl.PowertoolsCoreDataImportService"
          parent="coreDataImportService">
    </bean>

    <!-- Solr field value providers TEMPORARY FOR NOW SO DO NOT NEED TO DEPEND ON yb2bacceleratorcore -->

        <bean id="powertoolsCategoryCodeValueProvider" parent="abstractCategoryCodeValueProvider">
        <property name="categorySource" ref="powertoolsCategorySource"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="powertoolsBrandCategoryCodeValueProvider" parent="abstractCategoryCodeValueProvider">
        <property name="categorySource" ref="powertoolsBrandCategorySource"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="powertoolsVariantCategoryCodeValueProvider" parent="abstractCategoryCodeValueProvider">
        <property name="categorySource" ref="powertoolsVariantCategorySource"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="powertoolsCategoryNameValueProvider" parent="abstractCategoryNameValueProvider">
        <property name="categorySource" ref="powertoolsCategorySource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="powertoolsBrandCategoryNameValueProvider" parent="abstractCategoryNameValueProvider">
        <property name="categorySource" ref="powertoolsBrandCategorySource"/>
    </bean>

        <bean id="powertoolsCategorySource" parent="variantCategorySource">
        <property name="rootCategory" value="1"/> <!-- '1' is the root icecat category -->
    </bean>
    <bean id="powertoolsVariantCategorySource" parent="variantCategorySource"/>

    <bean id="powertoolsBrandCategorySource" parent="defaultCategorySource">
        <property name="rootCategory" value="brands"/> <!-- 'brands' is the root of the brands hierarchy -->
    </bean>

    <!-- Solr field value providers TEMPORARY FOR NOW SO DO NOT NEED TO DEPEND ON yb2bacceleratorcore -->


</beans>
```

this in `powertoolsspring-xml`

there is no folder as mystorestore because the directory is powertoolsstore in

```
<bean id="powertoolsSampleDataImportService" class="de.hybris.platform.powertoolsstore.services.dataimport.impl.PowertoolsSampleDataImportService" 
        parent="sampleDataImportService">
```

and for

```
 class="de.hybris.platform.powertoolsstore.setup.PowertoolsStoreSystemSetup"
```

mystore only has

mystore/initialdata/setup/InitialDataSystemSetup.java

and for

```
    <bean id="powertoolsSampleDataImportService" class="de.hybris.platform.powertoolsstore.services.dataimport.impl.PowertoolsSampleDataImportService" 
    parent="sampleDataImportService">
```

mystore doesnot havea services.

What should i do? I want to see localhost with items. so i thought best way is to copy from powertools?

Comment: update your system first.

Answer (score 1):

you solr indexer cron job is searching for bean 'mystoreBrandCategoryCodeValueProvider', so this bean should be defined in your spring file, remove it if not used.
possible solutions:

**1. update solr.impex :  remove this bean if you are not using it and import the impex via hac or update the system and make your your impex is being imported while system update.
Check your solrIndexedType if some old filed is using this bean, remove it (via hmc)**

**2.Add this bean into spring file if you are using it.**

Answer (score 1):

Hope you have copied all Impex correctly

Make sure

- Copy impex correctly in right folder path
  `/mystoreinitialdata/resources/mystoreinitialdata/import/sampledata/productCatalogs/mystoreProductCatalog/products-media.impex`
- Update powertool word reference with mystore
- Point siteResource to correct path
  `$siteResource=jar:com.mystore.initialdata.constants.MystoreInitialDataConstants&/mystoreinitialdata/import/sampledata/productCatalogs/$productCatalog`
- Correct the InitialDataSystemSetup class

Like

```
public static final String MYSTORE = "mystore";

@SystemSetup(type = Type.PROJECT, process = Process.ALL)
    public void createProjectData(final SystemSetupContext context)
    {
        final List<ImportData> importData = new ArrayList<ImportData>();

        final ImportData mystoreImportData = new ImportData();
        mystoreImportData.setProductCatalogName(MYSTORE);
        mystoreImportData.setContentCatalogNames(Arrays.asList(MYSTORE));
        mystoreImportData.setStoreNames(Arrays.asList(MYSTORE));
        importData.add(mystoreImportData);

        /* uncomment below line to test mystoreinitialdata */
                getCoreDataImportService().execute(this, context, importData);
                getEventService().publishEvent(new CoreDataImportedEvent(context, importData));
        
                getSampleDataImportService().execute(this, context, importData);
                getEventService().publishEvent(new SampleDataImportedEvent(context, importData));
    }
```

- Correct/Add the bean in your *core-spring.xml which you have used in your impex.

Like

```
<bean id="yAcceleratorInitialDataSystemSetup"
      class="com.store.initialdata.setup.InitialDataSystemSetup"
      parent="abstractCoreSystemSetup">
    <property name="coreDataImportService" ref="coreDataImportService"/>
    <property name="sampleDataImportService" ref="sampleDataImportService"/>
</bean>

<!-- Solr ValueProvider     -->

<bean id="mystoreCategorySource" parent="variantCategorySource">
    <property name="rootCategory" value="1" /> <!-- '1' is the root icecat category -->
</bean>

<bean id="mystoreVariantCategorySource" parent="variantCategorySource" />

<bean id="mystoreBrandCategorySource" parent="defaultCategorySource">
    <property name="rootCategory" value="brands" /> <!-- 'brands' is the root of the brands hierarchy -->
</bean>

<bean id="mystoreCategoryCodeValueProvider" parent="abstractCategoryCodeValueProvider">
    <property name="categorySource" ref="mystoreCategorySource" />
</bean>
<bean id="mystoreBrandCategoryCodeValueProvider" parent="abstractCategoryCodeValueProvider">
    <property name="categorySource" ref="mystoreBrandCategorySource" />
</bean>
<bean id="mystoreVariantCategoryCodeValueProvider" parent="abstractCategoryCodeValueProvider">
    <property name="categorySource" ref="mystoreVariantCategorySource" />
</bean>

<bean id="mystoreCategoryNameValueProvider" parent="abstractCategoryNameValueProvider">
    <property name="categorySource" ref="mystoreCategorySource" />
</bean>

<bean id="mystoreBrandCategoryNameValueProvider" parent="abstractCategoryNameValueProvider">
    <property name="categorySource" ref="mystoreBrandCategorySource" />
</bean>
```

- Update your system

Answer (score 0):

Update the running system! 
hac > Platform > Update

[image]